# Eclipse: Change JAR Location Application Wide

Tags: java, eclipse

I've got an external library exported as a JAR. That JAR is used within another application. I had to change the name of the library project and when I update the JAR the import location in the other application is no longer valid.

How can I update the application short of modifying every class that contains an import to that library manually?

Answer (score 0):

Good practice is to use Maven or Gradle project structure.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm not. Is there a refactor type method? I'm ok with a bit of manual labor, but hundreds of classes copying and pasting a new path is a little much.